# angularjs: Change parent scope from controller within a ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-switch

So, I can change a model value from a child controller, but when the child controller is in `ng-switch` then it doesn't work, why? I created [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/R7D8Xa1HBmYnwffbHQGD?p=preview) to demonstrate it.

One way to avoid this is to use the `.` in the model name, like `bunnies.kills`. Is this a bug or this is a feature ?

Using Angular 1.0.6

Comment: @sh0ber is correct. The reason is because `ng-switch` creates its own scope. Which means you really have two nested levels of scope from the parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your code structure, in your child controllers you would need to change:

```
$scope.$parent.kills++;
```

to

```
$scope.$parent.$parent.kills++;
```

**Explanation**: `MainCtrl`'s scope is the parent scope of `SimpleParentCtrl`, but the grandparent of `Step1Ctrl` and `Step2Ctrl`.  As some others pointed out, `ng-switch` creates its own scope, and then your `Step1Ctrl` and `Step2Ctrl` each created a child scope of the `ng-switch`.

**Note**: Each time the 1 or 2 button is clicked, both the `ng-switch` and it's currently matched child controller get a new scope.

**Also:** In case you happen to be looking in the Angular source and wondering how the `ng-switch` directive creates its own scope without a `scope` property, the answer is that it does so manually in its link method via `scope.$new()`.  The directives `ng-include`, `ng-switch`, `ng-repeat`, and `ng-view` all create new scope this way, either in the link method or the compile method's returned link function.

**Resources:**

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m

Answer (score 3):

ng-switch creates its own child scope, which is why @sh0ber's answer is one way to get it to work.  In general, [models should be referenced](http://youtu.be/ZhfUv0spHCY?t=30m) in controller scopes (hence reference objects), and not be not primitives.  So using a `.` is a "best practice".

This is not a bug, but it is not a feature either.  This is the way [JavaScript prototypal inheritance works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) with primitives.

Comment: Using a `.`? Can you explain?

Comment: @chovy, when you create an object in the parent scope (or better, reference one in the parent controller -- e.g., `$scope.refToSomeOtherObj = MyService.someObj;`), child scopes (such a child scope is created by the ng-switch directive) get a reference to that object.  So you can directly reference the object properties in the child scope: `$scope.refToSomeOtherObj.somePropertyOfSomeObj = ...`  I.e., you don't have to use `$parent`, which is a fragile way to code... should your controller hierarchy change, `$parent` may not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a slightly different approach to this problem.

Rather than use `$scope.$parent`, I would recommend you move all of your bunny killing logic into a shared service/model.

Also, I would try to avoid referencing parent views/controllers. Referencing the parent can make it difficult to reuse your code and can be painful to debug as the project grows. It is okay for a parent to know about it's children but a child should know little to nothing about it's parent.

Here is an updated Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/PLDbfU8Fu7m59A42qdR6?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>
        Dead bunnies: <strong>{{Elmer.deadWabbits}}</strong>
    </p>
    <div ng-controller="SimpleParentCtrl">
        <button ng-click="Elmer.killTheWabbit()">Kill from simple parent gun</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-switch="" on="step">
        <div ng-switch-when="first" ng-controller="Step1Ctrl">
            <button ng-click="Elmer.killTheWabbit()">Kill from 1 tab gun</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="second">
            <div ng-controller="Step2Ctrl">
                <button ng-click="Elmer.killTheWabbit()">Kill from 2 tab gun</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <p>
        <button ng-click="changeStep('first')">1</button> <button ng-click="changeStep('second')">2</button>
    </p>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('plunker', []).
service("Elmer", [function() {
    this.deadWabbits = 0;
    this.killTheWabbit = function() {
        this.deadWabbits++;
    };
}]).
controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Elmer) {
  $scope.Elmer = Elmer;
  $scope.step = 'first';
  $scope.changeStep = function(name){
    $scope.step = name;
  };
}).
controller('SimpleParentCtrl', function() {}).
controller('Step1Ctrl', function() {}).
controller('Step2Ctrl', function() {});
```

Comment: This is much better approach, and you'r right about the "child should know little to nothing about it's parent"

Answer (score 1):

> One way to avoid this is to use the . in model name, like bunnies.kills. Is this a bug or this is a feature ?

This has been explained numberous times : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance
and in mhevery's video